# How can I split a paragraph line in a text area. Pure Javascript please

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to write a simple markdown in JavaScript. Having problem with splitting a paragraph lines into a new line.

My code:

```js
function parseStr(str) {
  str.replace(/(.+)/gm, '<p>$1</p>');
}

var t = document.getElementById("textbox");

t.addEventListener("keyup", function() {

  var reOut = parseStr(t.innerText);

  document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = reOut;

});
```

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.subbox {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px;
  border: solid #981b1e;
  outline: none;
}

#textbox,
#div1 {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="subbox" id="textbox" contenteditable="true"></div>
  <div class="subbox" id="div1"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That `\s` will replace all white space. Use \n.

Comment: I used \n it didn't work.

Comment: It would be a lot more helpful if you could post example markdown.

Comment: @Utkanos, please see the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By reading your code I found that your main issue is that you are not returning anything from your `parseStr` function.

Try returning the replaced string:

```
function parseStr(str) {
  return str.replace(/(.+)/gm, '<p>$1</p>');
}
```

With this fixed and some small corrections to your code for readability, this is now working, see the example:

```js
const inputDiv = document.querySelector("#textbox");
const outputDiv = document.querySelector("#div1");

function parseStr(str) {
  return str.replace(/(.+)/gm, '<p>$1</p>');
}


inputDiv.addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  var reOut = parseStr(this.innerText);
  outputDiv.innerHTML = reOut;
});
```

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.subbox {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px;
  border: solid #981b1e;
  outline: none;
}

#textbox,
#div1 {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="subbox" id="textbox" contenteditable="true"></div>
  <div class="subbox" id="div1"></div>
</div>
```

## NOTE:

> *I would not recommend using innerHTML + RegEx if you are going to work with large amount of data (in this case, text).*

The reason why is that both of them are slow and could have a small impact in your application performance.

#### Alternative:

- **To replace the use of RegEx:**
  Use JavaScript's `split()` function to retrieve the lines inside your editable div.
- **To replace innerHTML:**
  Create the paragraph with JavaScript's `createElement("p")` and append the text using `innerText`.
- **To append to your output div:**
  Use `element.append([Elements Object])` instead of `element.innerHTML`.

The reason of this is that using `innerHTML` gives the task of parsing everything as HTML (even if it is only text) to JavaScript. It doesn't mean JavaScript can't handle HTML parsing, it just may have an effect on your application performance. That's why this note is nothing else than *a suggestion* if you did't already know about it.

And same thing happens with RegEx when using `str.replace()`.

**Alternative example:**

```js
const inputDiv = document.querySelector("#textbox");
const outputDiv = document.querySelector("#div1");

function parseStr(event){
  let str = event.target.innerText;
  //Clear the output first
  outputDiv.innerText = "";
  //Obtain every line break inside your editable div
  //and filter it (when pressing enter and not typing yet)
  let lines = str.split("\n").filter(l=>l!="");
  //Create a paragraph in JS for every line and 
  //append it to your output div
  lines.forEach((line)=>{
    let pElement = document.createElement("p");
    //Use innerText for the paragraph since you don't
    //need to have any other HTML inside it
    pElement.innerText = line;
    outputDiv.append(pElement);
  });
}

inputDiv.addEventListener("keyup", parseStr);
```

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.subbox {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px;
  border: solid #981b1e;
  outline: none;
}

#textbox,
#div1 {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="subbox" id="textbox" contenteditable="true"></div>
  <div class="subbox" id="div1"></div>
</div>
```